# Unable to enlarge linux partion size on gparted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted, memory-management

I've been trying to enlarge the linux partition of my system. Following online sources, I got some unallocated memory from the windows side, and then, moving to the ubuntu side, I installed gparted. However, despite the unallocated memory being right next to the linux partition, I'm not geting the [option to drag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYOCH.png) and enlarge the partition, as shown in the tutorials.

I went through some other similiar questions, and:

- No keys on the gparted screen.
- I disabled swap space from the terminal, but that did not help
- Gparted gives an error whenever I try to unmount.

What am I not doing? Am I supposed to do it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rzOO.jpg) on my startup menu (where I can switch between systems) like when I first dual booted?

[image]

Comment: Did you start the Linux system from the partition you want to resize? You cannot resize a mounted partition. You should start a live system from CD/DVD/USB pendrive.

Comment: Be sure to have good backups. You have to use live installer's gparted or gparted flash drive. You show tiny lock, so cannot edit that partition. You have to move partition left & then expand right. Alternative is to create new partition for /home and move /home folder out of / partition into new partition. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unallocated space is located *before* the Linux partition.
To be able to increase this partition, it should be located
*after* this partition.

Boot using the GParted live USB (or any other partition editor)
and move the Linux partition up, so it immediately follows the
Windows partition.

Now you will be able to resize up the Linux partition.

Take careful backups, as partition editing can be dangerous
in case of user error.